# CentOS not automatically started httpd in Vagrant

Tags: vagrant

If I use a symbolic link to httpd.conf at vagrant shared directory, it not automatically started httpd.
Where wrong my configuration?

Versions:

- Host OS: Mac OS X 10.9.2
- Guest OS: CentOS release 6.4 (Final)
- VirtualBox 4.3.2
- Vagrant 1.3.5
- Apache/2.2.15

For example:

```
$ vagrant ssh
[vagrant]$ sudo chkconfig httpd on
[vagrant]$ ln -sf /vagrant/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf
[vagrant]$ exit
$ vagrant reload
$ vagrant ssh
[vagrant]$ ps -ef | grep httpd
vagrant   2652  2632  0 16:40 pts/0    00:00:00 grep httpd
```

Thank you for being patient with my English.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Apache doesn't start after Vagrant reload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718785/apache-doesnt-start-after-vagrant-reload)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was problem related to vagrant folder mount.
I edited to wait vagrant sync folder mount to `/etc/init.d/httpd`.

Answer (score 0):

start the httpd:

```
service httpd start
```

if you want it to auto start when OS boot:

```
chkconfig --levels 234 httpd on
```

run a httpd.conf config test to see if there is error:

```
apachectl configtest
```

or

```
httpd -t
```

Comment: Thank you for your comments.

If I use no symbolic link "httpd.conf", the httpd is automatically started.

I want to use symbolic link. Do you know that method?

Comment: do you have error when you run httpd -t with symbolic link?

Comment: That result is "Syntax OK" and "service httpd start" is no problem. but it not automatically started httpd after vagrant up.

Comment: if you run: "chkconfig --levels 234 httpd on" this should allow the httpd to start during centos VM boot..

Answer (score 0):

All files in vagrant sync folder are owned by vagrant:vagrant. Please check this and the permission accordingly. Suggestion is to use provision to

- copy your `httpd.conf` to `/etc/httpd/conf`
- or `chown` and `chmod` accordingly