# Apache doesn't start after Vagrant reload

Tags: apache, centos, vagrant

I'm trying to set up a simple dev environment with Vagrant. The base box (that I created) has CentOS 6.5 64bit with Apache and MySQL.

The issue is, the httpd service doesn't start on boot after I reload the VM (`vagrant reload` or `vagrant halt` then `up`).

The problem only occurs when I run a provision script that alters the `DocumentRoot` and only after the first time I halt the machine.

#### More info:

httpd is on `chkconfig` on levels 2, 3, 4 and 5

There are no errors written to the error_log (on `/etc/httpd/logs`).

If I ssh into the machine and start the service manually, it starts with no problem.

I had the same issue with other CentOS boxes (like the `chef/centos-6.5` available on vagrantcloud.com), that's why I created one myself.

Other services, like mysql, start fine, so it's a problem specific to apache.

#### Resuming:

- httpd always start on first boot, even with the provision script (like after vagrant destroy)
- httpd always start when I don't run a provision script (but I need it to set the DocumentRoot)
- httpd doesn't start after first halt, with a provision script that messes with DocumentRoot (not sure if that's the problem).

---

This is my Vagrantfile:

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|

  config.vm.box = "centos64_lamp"
  config.vm.box_url = "<url>/centos64_lamp.box"
  config.vm.hostname = "machine.dev"
  config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8080
  config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/vagrant", owner: "root", group: "root"
  config.vm.provision :shell, :path => "vagrant_files/bootstrap.sh"

end
```

I tried to create the vagrant folder with owner/group `root` and `apache`. Same problem with both (as with owner `vagrant`).

These are the provision scripts (bootstrap.sh) that I tried. The only thing that I want them to do is to change the DocumentRoot to the vagrant folder. Neither worked.

Try 1

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo rm -rf /var/www/html
sudo ln -fs /vagrant/app/webroot /var/www/html
```

Try 2

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

sudo cp /vagrant/vagrant_files/httpd.conf /etc/httpd/conf
sudo service httpd restart
```

The httpd.conf on the second try is equal to the default one, except for the DocumentRoot path. This second alternative allows me to do `vagrant up --provision` to force the restart of the service, but that should be an unnecessary step.

What else can I try to solve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Apparently the problem was due to the vagrant folder not being mounted when Apache tries to start. Although I still don't understand why no error is thrown.

I solved it by creating an Upstart script (on the folder `/etc/init`) to start the service after vagrant mounts its folder (it emits an event called `vagrant-mounted`)

This is the script I used (with the filename `httpd.conf` but I don't think that's necessary).

```
# start apache on vagrant mounted

start on vagrant-mounted

exec sudo service httpd start
```

[Upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/) can do much more but this solves it.

Comment: I dropped `sudo` , and instead used `exec service apache2 restart` in ubuntu based boxes.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, check if `httpd` suppose to be started for specific runlevels (at least 2-5) by (which you did):

```
chkconfig | grep httpd
```

In that case it may be related that your DocumentRoot or its symlink points to [Vagrant synced folder](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/index.html), so it's not available yet during service being started.

Workaround is to add `service start httpd` command at the end of your shell provisioning script, e.g.:

```
service httpd status || service httpd start
```

in order to fix it.

For more bullet-proof workaround, add it into trap function (for Bash script), e.g.:

```
trap onerror 1 2 3 15 ERR

#--- onerror()
onerror() {
  service httpd status || service httpd start
}
```

This may be not enough, so to make it start in halt & up cases, you need to run your shell as `always` in your `Vagrantfile`, for example:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, run: "always", :inline => "service httpd status || service httpd start"
```

or provide a script, e.g.:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, run: "always", path: "scripts/check_vm_services.sh"
```

Then the script may look like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Script to re-check VM state.
# Run each time when vagrant command is invoked.

# Check if httpd service is running.
echo Checking services...
service httpd status || service httpd start
```

---

Alternatively check: [Launching services after Vagrant mount](http://razius.com/articles/launching-services-after-vagrant-mount/) which  uses [upstart event](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#event) that Vagrant emits each time it mounts a synced folder that is called vagrant-mounted, so we can modify the upstart configuration file for services that depend on the Vagrant synced folder to listen and start check and restart the services after the vagrant-mounted event is emitted.

Answer (score 0):

i confirm that the above ^ solution absolutely works.
i added a file named `vagrant-mounted.conf` within `/etc/init`, containing:

```
start on vagrant-mounted
exec sudo sh /etc/startup.sh
```

the shell script `/etc/startup.sh` i had already added, as a means of manually starting up httpd, mysqld and sendmail but required logging in via `vagrant ssh` after `vagrant up` to do so... now it's automatic. great!

Answer (score 0):

My nginx was not starting up on Vagrant reload or Vagrant up, so this is my solution:

```
sudo cat > /etc/init/vagrant-mounted.conf << EOL
# start services on vagrant mounted

start on vagrant-mounted

exec sudo service php5-fpm restart
exec sudo service mysql restart
exec sudo service memcached restart
exec sudo service nginx restart
exec sudo nginx
EOL
```